# Is it possible to query Stripe for a credit card belonging to any customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription service for which free trials are allowed before signing up for the full payed service. I want to ask the customer to provide credit card details before gaining access to the free trial, to prevent abuse of the trial.

I'm using Stripe to handle payments so that I don't have to deal with storage of any sensitive payment information. This free trial scenario would seem to be very common, so I assumed there would be some way to query a card to make sure that it hasn't been used to sign up already. Just some API call that would accept the card number etc. and return a boolean.

I haven't seen anything like in the API docs. I know that fingerprints of cards are accessible after creating a card source, so is it advisable to store them myself and query them? Or have I missed something in the docs?

Just to be clear... I'm not looking to search a card for a particular customer. I know I can iterate over the cards to do that, but I'd have to iterate over the cards of every customer to accomplish what I want, which is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Here you probaly want to contact the support team and suggest this as a new feature.
A possibility is the fingerprint you mention, in my opinion this would be the way i would do it too.

Answer (score 0):

**One single card should never be associated with one customer in a platform.**

No, there is no way to check whether a credit card is used for another customer or not. And there shouldn't be. Because a customer has right to use his/her single credit card to maintain more than accounts.

You can easily integrate trial feature of a Subscription in Stripe which is best way to implement Trial feature using Stripe. If any customer's payment failed after trial expired then you will be notified by Stripe.

**And Stripe and any other payment gateway is not advise to store any card info due to security issue.**